# AS3 Extended classes

Tags: actionscript-3, class, extends

Say I have a basic class "Code.as"
And I also have class "Code2.as" that extends "Code.as"

In "Code.as" I have the line "public static var code2:Code = new Code2();"

I keep getting this error:
"TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference"

at "Code2.as"s class declaration.

Why? I can't figure it out.
If "Code2.as" extends "Code.as" I thought it would be alright to address it as a "Code" as well...

Comment: Using the *type* of `Code` in `code2:Code` is just fine. However, that error sounds like it's more so a problem with `new Code2();`. Have you tried running your code with the debugger?

Comment: Without more details, I doubt anybody will be able to answer you.

Comment: Call me crazy, but wouldn't what you are trying to (assuming you get rid of whatever problem you are having) cause a stack overflow? Creating an instance of Code2 would create another instance of Code2, which in turn would create another instance of Code2 etc.

Answer (score -1):

The correct line should be:

```
public static var code2:Code2 = new Code2();
```

Also make sure you import "Code2":

```
import Code2;
```

Comment: Code2 extends Code, so a variable of type Code can contain an object of Code2. The null object reference error must be in a piece of code that isn't posted.

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing this so I could later reference it as a "Code" to avoid having to check the type first (there will be multiple entries). I know you can do this in java but didn't know you couldn't in AS3. @OmerHassan It gives the error at "Code2"s public class line, I have been referencing Code.code2.

Comment: @NathanWride, you need to post more code and enable the debugger so that you know exactly at what line the error is happening. The error indicates that you're trying to access a property of non-initialized object. The line you posted is completely unrelated.

Comment: With permit debugging, the line with the issue REALLY IS the class declaration of Code2. I have been setting an arrays index to Code.code2 e.g myArray[i] = Code.code2; Does that cause the error somehow?

Comment: I have a hard time wrapping my head around what you're trying to do. So, in your `Code` class, you have a static variable of type `Code` , which is in fact an instance of `Code2`; `Code2` itself extends `Code`? None of this can (or even *should*) work. You need to review the structure of your code and reduce the dependencies between the two classes. Perhaps make Code and Code2 extend the same base class?